# Механизм пополнения баланса и оплаты услуг на сайте. Помогите с терминологией:)

Tags: биллинг

Всем привет!
Добрались таки руки до моей многострадальной панельки-долгостроя.

Необходимо решить вопрос отъема денег у клиентов, пользующихся услугами моей панельки.

Я представляю это так.
Есть пользователь, и есть таблица users, в которой среди прочих пользовательских полей(имя, ник, емайл, итд), есть поле balance DECIMAL(12,2). По факту, значение из этого поля выводится на сайте везде, где это нужно(панель навигации, к примеру). Я так полагаю, что id пользователя одновременно является и счетом этого пользователя, а состояние счета как раз фиксируется в поле balance.

Каждый раз, когда пользователь вносит деньги на счет, или сработал биллинговый механизм, который запускается раз в сутки и тарифицирует потребляемые услуги, поле balance пересчитывается(ну, на всякий случай). Как на ваш взгляд - это правильный подход?

Когда пользователь хочет пополнить свой баланс, какой документ создается, счет(invoice), или заказ(order)? А когда я хочу протарифицировать услуги пользователя?. Нужно ли создавать сущность платеж(payment), и привязывать ее к создаваемому документы?

У пользователя одновременно может быть заказано несколько услуг(services), стоимость каждой просчитывается в момент заказа услуги, и прописывается в таблице services в поле cost. Услуги можно оплачивать только используя средства на счете, т.е., нельзя заказать услугу, или воспользоваться уже заказанной услугой при 0 или отрицательном балансе.

Прошу прощения за сумбурность. Задавайте интересующие вас запросы. Я создал этот топик, чтобы попытаться разобраться самому, ибо запутался :(

Comment: ведите историю всех транзакций. удобнее когда это одна таблица, которая может ссылаться на разные виды документов (платежи, пополнения). баланс можете апдейтить для удобства при изменениях в истории.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На купонном сайте я делал таблицу заказов.

Клиент создает заказ на покупку товара, или пополнение своего баланса. У заказа есть сумма к оплате, статус (новый, оплачен, ожидает оплаты и т.п.) и прочие атрибуты.

Созданный заказ нужно оплатить. Можно уйти на платежную систему, можно оплатить с баланса пользователя, если там достаточно средств.

У пользователя есть "баланс" — это деньги на его счету. Их можно потратить на оплату товара. Обновляется в момент подтверждения от платежной системы оплаты заказа типа "пополнить баланс" (+), или в момент оплаты с баланса покупки товара (–).

Т.о. две таблицы: пользователи-с-балансом, и заказы с суммой, user_id и статусом.

Comment: У вас по факту только заказы(orders) были?

Comment: Заказы разных типов:

 * товар
 * пополнение баланса, чтобы платить с него позже
 * бонусные акции - бесплатные, без оплаты
 * ещё какие-то были особенности